# printing child tags in xml file

Tags: python

I have an xml file with data that looks like this:

```
 <SpeechSegment spkid="S0">
  <Word dur="0.22" stime="0.44">oh</Word>
  <Word dur="0.27" stime="1.67">bedankt</Word>
  <Word dur="0.3" stime="2.03">voor</Word>
  <Word dur="0.53" stime="2.61">deelname</Word>
 </SpeechSegment>
```

What I want to do is count the words per segment and, if there are more than three words insert another "SpeechSegment" tag. So my preferred output is like this:

```
 <SpeechSegment spkid="S0">
  <Word dur="0.22" stime="0.44">oh</Word>
  <Word dur="0.27" stime="1.67">bedankt</Word>
  <Word dur="0.3" stime="2.03">voor</Word>
  #count is more than 3
  </SpeechSegment><SpeechSegment spkid="S0">
  <Word dur="0.53" stime="2.61">deelname</Word>
 </SpeechSegment>
```

I try to accomplish this using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
raw = ET.parse("Interview_short.xml")
root = raw.getroot()
for child in root:
 print(child)

 count_list = 0
 for item in child:
   print(item)
   count_list = count_list + 1
   if count_list > 2:
    #add speech segment tag
```

I have the problem however that

```
 print(child)
```

gives me this:

```
 <Element 'SpeechSegment' at 0x20e3cf8>.
```

While I am looking for

```
 <SpeechSegment spkid="S0">.
```

Adding .text after item does not work. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes of a tag by calling **.attrib** on the elements. In your case **child.attrib** will return the dictionary **{'spkid': 'S0'}**.

Now you can access the keys and values in the dictionary in the normal way for python.

```
child.attrib['spkid']
```

Hope that helps.

If you were also asking how to add the new tags as well, please specify that in your question.